# celery flower gives unknown worker

Tags: celery, flower

I'm using celery with redis backend.

i am passing CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND with the correct redis url and also the broker url to the Celery app config.

I start flower by giving the path to my Celery app with -A and also set the `--inspect_timeout=30` argument to allow for slow response from worker. I get Unknown worker 'celery@' when clicking on the worker in the UI.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refreshing the page at that screen solved it for me.

Answer (score -3):

There is a Refresh button on the dashboard page. It refreshes workers by resending inspect command. If you launch workers after flower just refresh workers.

The Refresh button is a choice under the drop down menu that has Shut Down selected by default. In order to Refresh, you have to select a worker (or all of them) first.According here:
https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/395

Comment: It is encouraged to include the relevant part of a link in the answer.